# How do I keep a YAML mapping represented as flow mapping {}, not multi-line block mapping?

Tags: perl, serialization, yaml

I have a YAML file *a.yaml*, which has the following:

```
allocations:
  hosts:
    - {name: xyz, farm: xyz1}
    - {name: xyz, farm: xyz1}
```

In my Perl script, I use `LoadFile('a.yaml')`, convert into a data structure and change the name, and when I dump the data structure, the YAML format is getting changed:

```
allocations:
  hosts:
    - farm: xyz1
      name: xyz
    - farm: xyz1
      name: xyz
```

But I want the YAML output to be as same like above *a.yaml* with the name changed in it:

```
allocations:
  hosts:
    - {name: xyz1, farm: xyz1}
    - {name: xyz1, farm: xyz1}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly, you may have to do this yourself if you must have it in the same format.  Having them line by line is still legal yaml, and exactly equivalent: you won't lose any data dumping it that way.